# iOS 5 UIButton title showing with ellipsis

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, ios5, ios6

I have a problem regarding the UIButton title in iOS5. They are clipped and show like in this photo. I don't want them to be clipped, i want to show the full title.

[image]

In iOS6, they work perfectly.

Please tell me how can i resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

you simply need to increase the width of your `UIButton` to show full `Title`, i have posted sample snippet for better idea, try it. You just need to increase the width of button.

```
UIButton *btn1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[btn1 setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 150, 25)];
[btn1 setTitle:@"This is Long Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:btn1];
```

Comment: I am creating the buttons in interface builder. They work fine in iOS6. I don't know why they are not working here.

Comment: may be you have not set autoresizing for interface builder.

Comment: autoresizing for ios5 will crash the app right away. Learned that lesson painfully.

Comment: @SamBudda i am not talking about that check box "auto layout", i am talking about size panel in inspector window of Interface builder

Comment: The real trick here is the setTitle call instead of setting the text on the titleLabel property directly.

Comment: just FYI if you just put self.button.titleLabel.text = @"xxxx", it will have the ellipsis as well. need to use [btn setTitleLabel: forState:]

Comment: salil and S.H are right, their comments are more useful than the real answer

Answer (score 1):

Guys i have found the solution.

It was pretty simple, you just need to set the button font size in the interface builder to a larger or the same font size than that of the UIapperance font proxy.

Comment: I had a very strange issue where the UIAppearance was conflicting and causing the ellipses issue only when building from an iOS 13 SDK on an iOS 14 Device. Resolved by removing the appearance settings for buttons and labels, as they were not really doing anything anyway

Answer (score 0):

I think AutoLayout may be the culprit for this. Check to see if your constraints aren't forcing the label to shrink.

Comment: I have autolayout turned off. I have used UIapperance to change the font of all buttons with UILabel *labelsApperance = [UILabel appearance];

And when i disable it the font apperance proxy, the button works fine.

Comment: Okay, I'm assuming that your custom font may be larger than the default one. Can you set the minimum font size to be smaller and set the line break to `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping`?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are setting your custom font from the code but you are setting the text for the buttons from the IB. So my simple explanation is that as @MichaelScaria said, your custom font is larger. The text is clipping because the size of the label inside the button is adjusted for the current font and size. Since you are changing the font and size after the text is set you need to re-set the title of the button or call 'sizeToFit' on that button.

Comment: I called sizeToFit on the button and it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you here due to ellipsis and use of `UIBarButtonItem` know that there is a `possibleTitles` property on `UIBarButtonItem` with docs that read:

Use this property to provide a hint to the system on how to correctly size the bar button item to be wide enough to accommodate your widest title. Set the value of this property to an NSSet object containing all the titles you intend as possible titles for the bar button item. Use the actual text strings you intend to display.

This property applies to bar button items placed on navigation bars or toolbars.

Comment: And also know that if you need to init your bar button item to an empty title you need to use @" " rather than @"" to avoid positioning issues (that was my experience anyways).